# How can I retrieve/generate a list source files for each chunk file in Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, manifest, source-maps, webpack-5

Using Webpack5, I need a manifest with the source files containing in each chunk. That is, for each file `[name].[id].[hash].js` (e.g. `myapp.931.48654ad6a4s6d.js`) created during build, I need a list of all files that were bundled in that chunk, for each chunk.

I have tried `webpack-assets-manifest` and `webpack-manifest-plugin`, but what they generate is not enough, as they only provide a list of files with and without hash, e.g.:

```
  "js/app.930.js": "/app/static/js/app.930.59370e27f67ee1c4d4b8.js",
```

I have tried as well Webpack's own `recordsPath` configuration, which was nearest to what I need, but this also is incomplete as does not list all files in each chunk, only the file that initiated the chunk split (the file which has `import('somefile')` and the 'somefile' name), e.g.:

```
{
  "chunks": {
    "byName": {
      "app": 143,
      "main": 179,
      "polyfills": 429,
      "runtime": 666,
      "vendor.common": 149
    },
    "bySource": {
      "0 ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-6.use!../../../../../../../../../../../Absolute/path/to/my/app/folder/fileThatUsesImportStatement.ext TheImportedFile.ext": 930,
    (...)
```

I need basically the information that each sourcemap (`.js.map`) provides in it's "sources", that is:

```
{
   (...)
   "file":"js/app.930.59370e27f67ee1c4d4b8.js",
   "sources":[
"webpack://dependencyname/../../../../../../../../../../../Absolute/path/to/my/app/folder/originalFilenameInThisChunk.ext",
"webpack://dependencyname/../../../../../../../../../../../Absolute/path/to/my/app/folder/anotherOriginalFilenameInThisChunk.ext"
   ],
   (...)
```

In sum, I am looking for a way to generate a manifest of chunkfile -> List of files in it, for example:

```
{
  "app.930.59370e27f67ee1c4d4b8.js": [
     "/path/to/my/app/folder/originalFilenameInThisChunk.ext",
     "/path/to/my/app/folder/anotherOriginalFilenameInThisChunk.ext",
     (...)
  ],
  "anotherchunkfile.js": [
      "/path/to/importedfiles.ext",
     (...)
   ],
  (...)
```

Is it possible somehow to retrieve this information in Webpack (maybe as a `plugin` entry, during build) without I manually needing to write a standalone code to read each `.map` file and do the json manually *(which will be ultra slow opening each map with fs.readfile)*?

Comment: Can’t you get a report from a bundle analyzer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: @morganney I have it, and it outputs `stats.json` exactly like `webpack-stats-plugin` with default options. Under each `chunk->modules->reasons` there's `module` which is what analyzer uses in it's report html: "../../some/path/to/file.ext + 3 modules" and I wondered if was another file for the bundle: I just realized the "+3" are omitted because are the loaders (babel, vue-loader, etc) and not part of the final chunk. Anyway, The `transform` from `webpack-stat-plugin` might be the way to do, as I'll already save the json with only the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the npm module [webpack-stats-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-stats-plugin) for this.

With this configuration for example:

```
const { StatsWriterPlugin } = require("webpack-stats-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new StatsWriterPlugin({
      stats: {
        fields: ["assets"]
      },
      filename: "stats.json",
    }),
  ],
};
```

It creates a detailed list in a JSON file (stats.json) of the files used.

The output looks something like this:

```
  "assets": [
    {
      "type": "asset",
      "name": "main.js",
      "size": 737766,
      "emitted": false,
      "comparedForEmit": false,
      "cached": true,
      "info": {
        "javascriptModule": false,
        "related": {
          "sourceMap": "main.js.map"
        }
      },
      ...
```

Comment: Though the plugin default options just provides same json as what `webpack-bundle-analyzer` gives and the answer per so isn't exactly what I need, the module suggestion is the key: It comes with extra options, especially the `transform` callback, which I can then "cherrypick" the information I need better _(which is located in "chunks" instead of "assets")_. Unless there's another answer with a more direct approach, I think that module's `transform` callback is the way to go. Thank you. _RIP build performance though, gotta nest forloops to get the info I need out of the huge stats object lol_

Comment: Marking as correct answer and assigning the bounty to this. The plugin suggestion was great and it's source code taught me more about the stat object and plugins as a whole. I started with the `transform` callback it provides, but later I ended up making my own plugin that exports the "bundle/chunk->all sources". Thank you @ztom